# Elastic Search Nest C# Syntax Error: using wildcard and multimatch within one query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a query where I want to have two clauses: one for `.MultiMatch` and one for `.Wildcard`. The wildcard is independent of the multimatch.

I can get them both working separately, but not together. The current error message in Visual Studio has the `Wildcard` word underlined and says the following:

`Querycontainer does not contain a definition for 'Wildcard'...`

Here is the code I am trying to implement. I have tried putting `.Wildcard` and `.MultiMatch` in separate `.Should` pieces but to no avail.

```
.Query(q => q
  .Bool(b => b
    .Should(m => m                             
      .MultiMatch(ma => ma
        .Fields(f => f.Field("_id")
          .Field("elements.location.city")
          .Field("ticket_number")
          )
          .Query(query)
        )
        .Wildcard(c => c
          .Field("name").Value(query.ToLower() + "*")
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

The `query` you see on line 8 is passed into this function as an argument.

As stated above, line 10 is the issue at hand as the Query container does not know what to do with Wildcard.

Any and all input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what boolean condition you want between the `MultiMatch` and `Wildcard` queries?

For example here, I am looking for records which satisfy both `MultiMatch` **AND** `WildCard` queries:

```
.Query(q => q
    .Bool(b => b
        .Must(m => m
            .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                .Fields(f => f.Field("FieldName"))
                .Query("MyKeyword")

            ), wc => wc
            .Wildcard(c => c
                .Field("FieldName")
                .Value("*Something*")
            )
        )
    )
));
```

If you want to **OR** them, use `Should` instead of `Must`: see [Bool Query Usage](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-query-usage.html)